# HL7 v2 structure

Tags: hl7-v2

I have a problem with how many instances in the image below are of each segment. I know that the MSH is 1 and the NTE is 0 to many but in the next Segments I am not sure how to deal with that. Is it 1 or 1 to many for ORC? 
Can anybody tell me the right number of each segment? That would be great.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAso5.png)

Answer (score 1):

Brackets [ ] mean the segment is optional.

Braces/curly brackets { } mean the segment may repeat.

```
MSH           - 1
[{NTE}]       - 0 to many
{ORC          - 1 to many (start of ORC group)
  [OBR        - 0 to 1 (start of OBR group)
    ZDS       - 1 
    [{NTE}]   - 0 to many
    [{DG1}]   - 0 to many
    [{OBX}    - 0 to many (start of OBX group)
      [{NTE}] - 0 to many
    ]         - (end of OBX group)
  ]           - (end of OBR group)
}             - (end of ORC group)
```

**Note the grouping of segments by the matching opening/closing braces and brackets**. So in your example, even though ZDS is 1, that only applies if there is an OBR segment.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313746/what-do-brackets-and-braces-mean-in-hl7-segments) that may be of interest, and it also contains some helpful links.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm Dale's answer.

You can use the [Caristix HL7-Definition website](https://hl7-definition.caristix.com/v2/HL7v2.5.1/TriggerEvents/ADT_A01) to know the trigger event structure and optionality/repetition requirements.

In the Optionality column, 
R = the segment is required
O = the segment is optional

In the Repeatability column,
- = not repeatable
∞ = repeatable
n = repeatable n times